# How to conditionally select text inside span tag

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my html markup [image]

I have following structure in html:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span>
        <span class="menu-item-text">Home1  </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>



<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span>
        <span class="menu-item-text">Home2</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

On the above structure i am trying to extract text value from all span and if value happens to me(Home1) then  alert?

How would i do that using jquery.

Comment: You should show what you have tried....StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. If you haven't tried anything it shouldn't be hard to at least get a good start with some web searching

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 

var al =$('.menu-item-text').html();

if (al=="Home1")
{
alert(al);
}

});

Comment: you need to loop through them all and check each instance. Also please update question with formatted readable code , don't drop it in comment blocks

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Explain what actual use case will be. Using an alert is not likely it

Comment: if ($('span:contains("Home1")')) is true apply background image to <li> aligned left.

Comment: no need for an `if()` .. just use the selector and method ... `$('span:contains("Home1")').addClass('some-new-class')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery :contains selector.

```js
if ($('span:contains("Home1")').length > 0) {
  alert("home1")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span>
        <span class="menu-item-text">Home1  </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>



<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span>
        <span class="menu-item-text">Home2</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `$(selector)` will always return true even when a selector match isn't found since `$()` always returns an object. Have to check length of resultant collection

Comment: You are right, I meant to add `.length > 0` to the end, I just fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery

```
$(".menu-item-text").click(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Home1"){ 
        alert("wohoo"); 
    };
});
```

Comment: This works now i want to add a background image to its father how do i do that. On my case if condition is true can i add background image to its list item.

Comment: Check the parent() and closest() jQuery functions

Comment: If that is the correct answer,mark is please. Your comment is just anozher question not related to the original one